# How to find that how many sells were in each city and what is proportion for each city of total in percentage in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find out how many sells were made in each city. After that i should convert it into percentage and find out the proportion of total for each city in percentage.

```
select distinct(Dimension.City.City), sum(fact.sale.Profit) as summ, 
    fact.sale.Profit * 100/(SELECT SUM(fact.sale.Profit) FROM fact.sale) as 'Percentage of Total'
    from Dimension.City 
    inner join Fact.Sale 
    on Dimension.City.[City Key] = Fact.Sale.[City Key]
    group by Dimension.city.City, fact.sale.Profit
    order by sum(fact.sale.Profit) desc
```

Results: *(Only some part)*

```
   City                summ       Percentage of Total        

Cherry Grove Beach    22770.00    0.0088534614705504  
Idaho City            19320.00    0.0075120279144064  
Accomac               18400.00    0.0107314684491520  
Gasport               18400.00    0.0107314684491520  
Newberg               18400.00    0.0107314684491520
```

Comment: A `DISTINCT` with a `GROUP BY` is always a sign of a flaw in your query. A `GROUP BY` already causes your data to be returned in *distinct* sets, so if you are getting duplicates, it likely means your `GROUP BY` is wrong. Otherwise the `DISTINCT` is redundant and unneeded overhead. I would suggest the former here, as you are both aggregating and grouping on `fact.sale.Profit`. Also, `DISTINCT` isn't a function, it's a **set** operator. It's not `DISTINCT({expression})` it's `SELECT DISTINCT ... `.

Comment: Also [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. You are far better off aliasing your objects in the `FROM` and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Select D.City, D.summ, D.summ/ SUM(D.summ) Over () As [Percentage of Total]
From
(
  Select A.City, SUM(B.Profit) As summ
  From City A
  Join Sale B
  On A.City_Key = B.City_Key
  Group By City
) D
Order By D.summ DESC
```

`SUM(B.Profit)` : to find the sum of profits for each city.

`SUM(D.summ) Over ()` : to find the total profits among all cities, sum of sum(Profit).

See a demo from [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=18ba3ddac506b1f326253249d0f05717).